# insert query giving error on form submit

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have html form

```
    <form name="booksInput" action="theGamer.php" method="post">
    Book Name: <input type="text" name="books">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="subBooks">
</form>
```

the php code for grabbing and then inserting the value is below

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","","library");
$book=$_POST['books'];
$sql="INSERT INTO books (bID, book) VALUES ('','$_POST['books']')";
if (!mysql_query($con,$sql))
{
 die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
 }
echo "1 record added";
```

and this is mysql Table

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| bID   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| book  | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

but its giving me error  parse error, expecting `T_STRING' or`T_VARIABLE' or `T_NUM_STRING' in C:\wamp\www\library\theGamer.php on line 8

Comment: Not sure if this is the source of your problem, but the nested single quotes in `$sql="INSERT INTO books (bID, book) VALUES ('','$_POST['books']')";` will definitely cause issues. Why don't you just use the `$book` variable here instead of `$_POST['books']`?

Comment: $sql="INSERT INTO books (bID, book) VALUES ('','$book')"; write this simply you can also remove '' from '$_post['books']' and write '$_post[books]';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{}` around values

```
$sql="INSERT INTO books (bID, book) VALUES ('','{$_POST['books']}')";
```

**Your code is vulnerable for sql injection, use `Mysqli` OR `PDO` with prepared statements.**

**Edit**

Also `mysql_query()` requires first parameter as sql query

```
mysql_query($con,$sql)
```

should be

```
mysql_query($sql,$con)
```

**Edit2**

You haven't selected database too. Use `mysql_select_db` for that.

Comment: @JaneMarjana Because you haven't written `mysql_select_db("database_name",$con);` after `mysql_connect`. Write it down your problem will be solved.

Comment: done it runs now without error but in $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","","library"); i have given the db name i.e library

Comment: @JaneMarjana `mysql_connect` don't take parameter for database name, its `mysqli_connect` which take database name as 4th parameter. :)

Answer (score 1):

the $sql var should be:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO books (bID, book) VALUES ('','$_POST[books]')";
```

simply remove the ' from $_POST['books']

Comment: $sql="INSERT INTO `books` (`bID`, `book`) VALUES ('','$_POST[books]')";

Answer (score 0):

Try this one query:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO books (bID, book) VALUES (NULL,'{$_POST['books']}')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have extra quotes in the POST.

Personally not a fan of putting arrays directly in a string rather than concatenating them so try this:-

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","","library");
$book=$_POST['books'];
$sql="INSERT INTO books (bID, book) VALUES ('','".$_POST['books']."')";
if (!mysql_query($sql, $con))
{
 die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
 }
echo "1 record added";
```

Note that you are also leaving yourself wide open to an SQL injection attack. To avoid that with minimal work:-

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","","library");
$book=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['books']);
$sql="INSERT INTO books (bID, book) VALUES ('','$book')";
if (!mysql_query($sql, $con))
{
 die('Error: ' . mysql_error($con));
 }
echo "1 record added";
```

Comment: now its giving this error mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in C:\wamp\www\library\theGamer.php on line 10

Comment: Parameters the wrong way round in the brackets for mysql_query.

Answer (score 0):

Use **$books** in query instead:

```
$books = $_POST['books'];
$sql   = "INSERT INTO books (bID, book) VALUES ('','$books')";
```

Comment: i edited my code accordingly but dont work $book=$_POST['books'];
$sql="INSERT INTO books (bID, book) VALUES ('','$book')";

Comment: You have not selected the database.

mysql_select_db('your database name',$con);

Comment: $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

mysql_select_db('library',$con);

Then you can continue insertion.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is messed up with the quotation marks. Its good to use braces if you are using super globals or arays inside quotation marks. The correct statement should look like.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO books (bID, book) VALUES ('','{$_POST['books']}')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, use the **Parameters** and **PDO** if you can.

You will say "Thank you" to yourself years later.

http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php and http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php

But now you need to do this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO books (bID, book) VALUES ('','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['books'])."')";
```

as @Kickstart said